# Android: getLayoutInflater Not work in static class

Tags: android, class

I want use `getLayoutInflater` in `static` `class`

But not work after run this code :

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout post = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.post);
        Commands.readD(post);
    }
}
```

Commands.java

```
public class Commands {

    public static void readD(LinearLayout viewPost) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View viewIn = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewIn, null);
        final TextView txtNd = (TextView) viewIn.findViewById(R.id.txtNd);
        viewMain.addView(viewIn);
    }
}
```

This line error is :

> The method getLayoutInflater() is undefined for the type Commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pass `Activity` through method

```
public static void readD(LinearLayout viewPost,Activity context) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
     //do your stuff
}
```

And in onCreate()

```
 Commands.readD(post,this);
```

**OR**

```
public static void readD(LinearLayout viewPost) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = viewPost.getContext().getLayoutInflator();
     //do your stuff
}
```

as  ρяσѕρєя K  mention..

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Just use `viewPost.getContext().getLayoutInflater()`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK wrong: `getLayoutInflater()` is not a method of `Context`

Answer (score 2):

Actually you need `context` in your static class

```
public static void readD(LinearLayout viewPost,Activity context) {

LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater()
 ......
}
```

### OR

another way is

```
public static void readD(LinearLayout viewPost) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = viewPost.getContext().getLayoutInflator();
 //do your stuff
}
```

as @ρяσѕρєя K mention

Comment: `getLayoutInflater()` is not a method of `Context`

Comment: @pskink I am not talking about method but you can access it via `context`

Comment: quote: "getContext().getLayoutInflater()", also, dont use misleading names like "Activity context"

Answer (score 1):

The error occurred because you can not achieve LayoutInflater without **Context**. I suggest you pass a Context param in your method such as:

```
  public class Commands {

    public static void readD(LinearLayout viewMain,Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View viewIn = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewIn, null);
        final TextView txtNd = (TextView) viewIn.findViewById(R.id.txtNd);
        viewMain.addView(viewIn);
    }
}
```